# Is it possible to prioritize wifi networks and bluetooth connections?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I can connect my camera to my phone over WifiI have a camera that can create its own access point, so that I can connect to it using an app on my phone.

When I activate the wifi on my phone however, it always picks my home network first, probably because it's the strongest signal.

Is it possible to configure Android to prioritize connecting to my camera's wifi, if available?

(I have the same problem with Bluetooth: when I want to connect my wireless headphones, it connects to the hifi speakers).

Comment: If your device is rooted, it's possible by adding `priority` to `wpa_supplicant.conf` file(s).

Comment: Gravitybox Xposed module features this, but requires a rooted device with Xposed Framework installed.